# How can I swap an image in MS Word 2021?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, images

[support.microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/replace-or-delete-a-picture-in-microsoft-office-f50c4431-a785-49d1-9ee5-a732947cbf1a) says:

> 1. Select the picture you want to replace.
> 2. Select the Picture Format (or Format) tab, and then select Change Picture:
>    [image]

However I don't see that icon:

[image]

I also don't see anything interesting in the contextual menu:

[image]

I also don't see anything interesting in the customized Ribbon: no `change picture`, no `replace picture`, no `swap picture`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I swap an image in MS Word 2021?

Comment: Have you tried to repair it?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thank you. Do you mean repairing the Word document?

Comment: I mean the MS Office installation. I don't have your version, but "Change Picture" should be there. Before repairing, see if you can find it if you customize the ribbon.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thanks, I haven't. A bit radical for my rather modest need, so I may wait :)

Comment: Have you checked if "Change Picture" is listed in Customize ribbon?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thanks good idea, I also don't see anything interesting in the customized Ribbon: no `change picture`, no `replace picture`, no `swap picture`.